# How to make each of these buttons when triggered, to make a different sound?

Tags: html, reactjs, button, audio, html5-audio

```
<div className="wrap">
      <div id="tiles" className="columns">
      <div id="ti">
   <button id ="Q" className='drum-pad'>Q</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>W</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>A</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>S</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>D</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>S</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>Z</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>X</button>
   <button className='drum-pad'>C</button>

   </div>
   </div>
     ...
```

Hello  I am using React, I would like to trigger certain sounds when one of the buttons is clicked (example: Q is pushed, it trigger a piano sound) but nothing of what I did seems to work can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need a couple of things.

1. Add some audio tags to your html.
2. Setup click handler(s) for your buttons.
3. Pass the element of the clicked button to match the sound to the button. Here I'm using the attribute of the button to match up with the required sound. `data-sound`.

```js
const playDrum = function(elem) {
  const sound = (elem.getAttribute("data-sound"));
  const audioElement = document.querySelector(`audio[data-sound="${sound}"]`);
  audioElement.currentTime = 0;
  audioElement.play();
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("drum")).forEach(
  function(element, index, array) {
    element.onclick = function() {
      playDrum(element)
    };
  }
);
```

```html
<button class="drum" data-sound="Q">Q</button>
<button class="drum" data-sound="W">W</button>
<audio data-sound="Q" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/tom-mid.wav"></audio>

<audio data-sound="W" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/hihat-close.wav"></audio>
```